# how many child records can an object have in a lookup relationship?

Tags: api, governorlimits, salesforce2salesforce

Does anyone knows how many records can an object have in a lookup relationship?

I've found in the documentation that as a best practice, don't exceed 10,000 child records for a master-detail relationship.But how about for a normal lookup relationship? If I have an object called "Warehouse" could it be referenced more than 10000 times on "Item" object?

Comment: Note that the "limits" in the documentation are really best practices, not real, actual limits. If you exceed those limits, you may experience problems with some kinds of queries, triggers, flows, etc.

Comment: I agree it's the same question, but won't unilaterally vote to close here. Let the community decide!

Comment: Thanks guys, that link solved my question. I appreciate your help.